# Nginx is downloading file instead of doing MySql query

Tags: mysql, nginx, php7

I encounter a very strange problem when I try to setup NGINX to use PHP and MySQL.

At first, everything seems to be fine and working. But that impression only lasts until there's a SQL query (at least that's my impression). And instead of passing the result of the query to PHP I get prompted to download a file with type application/octet-stream.

When I'm using SQLite or no database at all, everything is fine though. Does anybody have an idea why this is hapening?

When I have a look into my php info, it get this result:

> Additional .ini files parsed:
>
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-imagick.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-imap.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-intl.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-json.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-memcache.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-pspell.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-recode.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-tidy.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-wddx.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xmlrpc.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xsl.ini

And this is my mysql configuration (also from PHP info):

[image: MySQL settings]

As you can see, the mysqlnd static shows 0?!

I'm trying to do this with wordpress as well as "[Ionize](http://ionizecms.com/)". Ionize is also showing me some MySQL error:

[image: Error inside of Ionize (MySql error)]

Does anybody know how to solve (or at least debug since there are no errors inside the log files) this?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

In Nginx configuration files, located in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`, you have the http2 protocol turned on in the configuration files for the port 80. Just replace the `listen 80 http2;` with `listen 80;`.

Answer (score 0):

nginx doesn't download files, it just sends HTTP responses.
Nginx is usually is responsible for setting the `Content-Type:` field on the HTTP header and as a default, 
nginx uses a [MIME](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#default_type) of application/octet-stream as a fallback when it can't determine the content type.
When a browser receives a header with this content type, it will prompt the download action, as application/octet-stream is the MIME type for binary files.
This to me is an indication that nginx isn't configured properly because when it `fastcgi_pass`es properly it returns the `html/plain` header.
You can also set the mime type directly

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types

or this snippet will set the default MIME for nginx to `text/plain`

```
sudo cp /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.backup
# change application/octet-stream to text/plain
sudo sed -i 's/default_type application\/octet-stream/default_type text\/plain/' 
    /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Also, if you get nginx and PHP configured correctly and sending the right `Content-Type:` headers, browsers like Chrome will continue to cache the previous values - so it will continue to prompt a download.
This can be overcome, by opening developer tools, going in the the settings for the developer tools themselves and then clicking *disable cache* (while dev tools is open)

Comment: Replaced application/octet-stream with text/plain and restarted nginx (service nginx restart), but it will still give me a application/octet-stream to download. :-/

But inside the developer tools I see that the response is "AAASBAAAAAAAAAMAAACAAAQAAAAAAAUA////AAAECAAAAAAAf/8AAAAACAcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB".

In IE it's not downloading anything, instead it's just showing "€ÿÿÿÿ"